# List of file name's last 20 character in a dirctory

Tags: batch-file

I need to find a last 20 characters of list of files in a directory using a batch program and need to write it in a text file. Sample list of file names will be as below

```
PIOPROD.FromXMLInput_20150204082113__0007.txt
PIOPROD.GVRBOS_TEV_15351_20150209_202729_048064_00_048064_0005_20150209_25GGI_1_0250_FOD_607_2_20150210142010__0979.txt
PIOPROD.VERMAUSZUG_14803_20150116_195001_401118_401118_0501_01_01_0000_0501_00_01_20150213020051__0489.txt
```

I do have a sample .bat program, but it doesn't work. Kindly help me here

```
@ECHO ON
cd C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    SET var2=%f:~-20%
    echo %var2% > C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya\log\output.txt
    PAUSE
)
PAUSE
```

This command works fine when i manually enter each and every command in command prompt. But when I put all the command in a batch file all together, it doesn't work. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

This code may work.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
PUSHD C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya
SET "fFile="
FOR %%f in (*.txt) do (
    SET "fFile=%%~nf"
    SET "var2=!fFile:~-20!" 
    ECHO !var2! >> C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya\log\output.txt
)
```

Comment: Looks good, except for when a file name contains `!` (unlikely, but it can happen)

Comment: Also, PUSHD or CD /D should be used.

Comment: @dbenham I changed CD with PUSHD as is your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure batch solution. Note use of PUSHD instead of CD. (Could have used `cd /d`). Also toggle delayed expansion on and off within loop to protect any potential `!` in file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd "c:\users\senthlraja\desktop\remya"
>"log\output.txt" (
  for %%F in (*.txt) do (
    set "file=%%F"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo !file:~-20!
    endlocal
  )
)
popd
```

Here is a one liner using [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that renames files via regular expression replacement. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jren "^.*?({.{1,20})$" $1 /list /p "C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya" >"C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya\log\output.txt"
```

Use CALL JREN if you put the command within another batch script.

Answer (score 0):

With a [subroutine call](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) (*updated* according to dbenham's comment; truly I don't know where's origin of previous short circuit...)

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya
rem type nul>C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya\log\output.txt
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    SET "var2=%%~nxf"
    Call :DoItForMe
)
PAUSE
goto :DoNext

:DoItForMe
    echo %var2:~-20%>>C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya\log\output.txt
    echo %var2:~-20%
    rem PAUSE
goto :eof

:DoNext
```

or with [Delayed Expansion Variables within loops](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
cd C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya
rem type nul>C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya\log\output.txt
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    SET "var2=%%~nxf"
    echo !var2:~-20!>>C:\Users\SENTHLRAJA\Desktop\Remya\log\output.txt
    echo !var2:~-20!
    PAUSE
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Your first code is totally broken - `%%f` is not visible to your subroutine. Your second code will fail if any file name contains `!`.